# Is there a way for Apache to only set a header if it is unset?

Tags: apache, x-frame-options

Is there a way to have a HTTP header set globally by Apache only if this header is not set by application code?

For example, can Apache set the `X-Frame-Options` header by default to "SAMEORIGIN", unless this header is set to "DENY" via PHP?

e.g.,

Apache configuration **httpd.conf**:

```
Header set (only if unset) X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Application code (PHP):

```
<?php header('X-Frame-Options: DENY'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

In the Apache configuration **httpd.conf**, use the following directive:

```
Header setifempty X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```